# Deconstruct element in array and then join again

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add letter "x" to each word in array. It's not problem to add it to each *element* inside array, but in my case second element consists of two words.

As I understand, it should be somehow deconstructed from `'bar baz'` to `'bar','baz'`, then letter `x` added to `bar` and `baz`, and then `'barx'` and `'bazx'` should be merged to `'barx bazx'`. But I don't sure.

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar baz'];

// Pass a function to map
const map = array.map(word => word + 'x');

alert(map);
// Desired output: foox,barx bazx
// For obvious reasons, current output is foox,bar bazx (with no x after bar).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the items and add the `'X'` for every splitted element and join the items again for mapping.

```js
const plusX = s => s + 'x';

var array = ['foo', 'bar baz'],
    result = array.map(
        s => s
            .split(' ')
            .map(plusX)
            .join(' ')
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on your definition of "word". E.g. is 'a+b' a single word, two words 'a' and 'b' or three words 'a', '+' and 'b'?

One straightforward solution is to match a regex pattern and add 'x' to all matched words:

```js
const array = ['foo', 'bar baz'];

// Append 'x' to all words:
const map = array.map(str => str.replace(/\w+/g, word => word + 'x'));

console.log(map);
```

Here, the regex `\w+` matches words which are made up of characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore _ only. So it would replace 'a+b' with 'ax+bx'.

Answer (score 1):

Set separator and split every element

```js
const array = ["foo", "bar baz"];

const separator = " ";

// Pass a function to map
const map = array.map(word =>
  word
    .split(separator)
    .map(element => `${element}x`)
    .join(separator)
);

alert(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, just add `word.replace(" ", "x ")` to insert `x` to the end of the previous word and before the white space:

```js
var array = ['foo', 'bar baz'];

const map = array.map(word => word.replace(" ", "x ") + "x");

alert(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.from()`, defined `"x"` as default parameter at `thisArg`, use `RegExp` `/(\w$)|(\s)/g` at `.replace()` to match word character at end of string or space character

```js
var array = ['foo', 'bar baz'];

// Pass a function to map
const map = Array.from(array, (word, index, prop = "x") =>
              word.replace(/(\w$)|(\s)/g, (_, p1, p2) => 
                p1 ? `${p1}${prop}` : `${prop}${p2}`));

console.log(map);
```

Comment: hm, `thisArg` is the last parameter of `Array.from` which you don't supply. You just declare an additional callback parameter which would be undefined if you weren't assigning a default value of 'x'. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @le_m That is correct. Attempted to set `thisArg` first, though was not able to. Am considering asking a Question as to that following further tests to determine if the case is user error

Comment: I like supplying parameters such as 'x' via `thisArg`, too, but it comes with the drawback that only a traditional `function` receives this parameter via its `this`. It's pretty useless when using the more elegant arrow functions.

Comment: @le_m Got it. Have to explicitly use `this`